# Read a log file line by line

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to read a file line by line and look out for lines that contain the string "Inside /buyairtime" in it, then get the AppSessionId from that line, after that use the AppSessionId to get the requestBody that should be in the next line and retrieve the transactionId.

I am able to read the file and get the AppSessionId but I am not able to get the "requestBody", please any help will be appreciated.

here is what I have tried.

```java
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader)) {
    br.lines().forEach((line) -> {

        if (line.contains("Inside /buyairtime")) {
            String[] item = line.split("\\|");
            String AppSessionId = item[1].trim();
            logger.info("SessionId =" + sessionId + " AppSessionId =" + AppSessionId);

            if (line.contains(AppSessionId) && line.contains("requestBody")) {
                String[] request = line.split("\\|");
                String requestBody = request[2].replace("#", "").trim();
                logger.info("SessionId =" + sessionId + " requestBody =" + requestBody);
            }
        }
    });

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Ex: here is an example of lines to read

```
[http-nio-8090-exec-66] g.c.v.M.controller.ApiController         : AppSessionId | MB-9672588DE0304D7 | ######## Inside /buyairtime Route

g.c.v.M.controller.ApiController         : AppSessionId | MB-9672588DE0304D7 | ######## requestBody = {"amount":"4.0","msisdn":"233200906179","transactionid":"0000001853861312"}

g.c.v.M.controller.ApiController         : AppSessionId | MB-9672588DE0304D7 | ######## Client IP = 127.0.0.1
```

here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9w7t.jpg) of the part of the file

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: You can't do it with a Stream, as you can't see two lines at once, unless you devise a `Collector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change the whole code to a non `forEach` loop like this (taking into consideration that the next line **will** have the request body!)

```java
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader))
{
    for(String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine())
    {
        if (line.contains("Inside /buyairtime"))
        {
            String[] item = line.split("\\|");
            String AppSessionId = item[1].trim();
            logger.info("SessionId =" + sessionId + " AppSessionId =" + AppSessionId);

            line = br.readLine(); // Jump to the next line
            if (line.contains(AppSessionId) && line.contains("requestBody"))
            {
                String[] request = line.split("\\|");
                String requestBody = request[2].replace("#", "").trim(); // Replace everything and get only the request body...
                logger.info("SessionId =" + sessionId + " requestBody =" + requestBody);
            }
        }
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As you can see, I jump into the next line to get the ReqBody, your logic was not correct before, since you supposed to read the both lines at the same time.